# HERE GET batch geocoding response 403 but job is complete

Tags: here-api

I successfully submitted a batch geocoding request...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <RequestId>CAOxHo4SFaj17sSB2UyTxeoDKHZR77f9</RequestId>
        </MetaInfo>
        <Status>accepted</Status>
        <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
        <ValidCount>0</ValidCount>
        <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
        <ProcessedCount>0</ProcessedCount>
        <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
        <SuccessCount>0</SuccessCount>
        <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
    </Response>
</ns2:SearchBatch>
```

And when I GET status, the job is completed....

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <RequestId>CAOxHo4SFaj17sSB2UyTxeoDKHZR77f9</RequestId>
        </MetaInfo>
        <Status>completed</Status>
        <JobStarted>2019-10-31T00:11:58.000Z</JobStarted>
        <JobFinished>2019-10-31T00:12:26.000Z</JobFinished>
        <TotalCount>13291</TotalCount>
        <ValidCount>13291</ValidCount>
        <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
        <ProcessedCount>13291</ProcessedCount>
        <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
        <SuccessCount>13291</SuccessCount>
        <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
    </Response>
```

However, when I then go to get the response, I get 403 forbidden

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /
        on this server.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using the endpoint outlined here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/example-get-results.html

Comment: please pass correct request ID, app_id and app_code to download the result. Also refer developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/example-get-results.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to pass correct apikey to download the result.

```
https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/CAOxHo4SFaj17sSB2UyTxeoDKHZR77f9/result?apiKey={}
```

Also refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-get-results.html